# When converting a position from my HUD viewport to my game-area viewport, why are the Y-values incorrect on my android app?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, viewport, scene2d

I'm building a mobile Box2D body/joint editor in libGDX, but I'm getting inconsistent results between my desktop and android builds, the android build producing incorrect position Y-values. In summary, the editor consists of a HUD with its own FitViewport for consistent screen presence, and the actual build area grid with its own FitViewport that can be navigated and zoomed, much like any run-of-the-mill image editor. The user touches the screen, and a target appears above that position that can be dragged around to select points on the grid, connecting points that serve as the vertices of the shapes that will become Box2D bodies. This target-selector exists on the HUD viewport so that it can remain a static size if the user were to zoom in on the grid area. So, in order to select a point on this grid, I have to convert the target's position in the HUD viewport to screen coordinates, then convert it to that point on the build area grid. Next to the target, I have a BitmapFont that renders text of the targets current position.

So here's an example of my problem. Let's say the target is at the arbitrary point (0,0) on the grid. The text would say "0,0". In my desktop build it does this accurately. In my Android build, the Y-value is offset by varying values, based on camera zoom, even though that point is without a doubt (0, 0) in that space(The bottom-left of the grid is coded at 0,0). I don't understand how this could happen, since both builds share the core module where this code resides. I knew this would be hard to explain, so I took some screen shots.

These images show the desktop build, no issues, correct values:

[desktop app image, default zoom, y-value is correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvVKI.png)

[desktop app image, camera zoomed in, y-value is still correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlMwD.png)

These images show the android build, y-value is incorrect but becomes more correct as the camera zooms in:

[android app image, default zoom, y-value is way off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eRoA.png)

[android app image, zoomed in, y-value is closer to correct but still off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivNVS.png)

I really want to show some code, but I have no idea which parts are relevant to this issue. Essentially what is happening is that the user touches the screen, the target pops up 200px (HUD stage local) above that point, the targets position is converted to screen coordinates, then unprojected to build area grid coordinates. What gets me is that the Y-values are correct in the desktop build, so why would they be different in the android build. Here is my TargetSelector class where everything goes down:

```
public class TargetSelector extends Group {

    private ShapeRenderer shapeRenderer;

    private BitmapFont font;

    private Vector2 position;
    private float yOffset;
    private boolean targetActive;

    private Vector2 unprojectedPosition;
    private OrthographicCamera linkedCamera;
    private boolean hasLink = false;

    public TargetSelector(){
        initShapeRenderer();
        initTargetFields();
        initFont();
        initInputListener();
    }

    private void initShapeRenderer(){
        shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();
        shapeRenderer.setAutoShapeType(true);
        shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.RED);
    }

    private void initTargetFields(){
        unprojectedPosition = new Vector2();
        position = new Vector2();
        yOffset = 200;
        targetActive = false;
    }

    private void initFont(){
        font = new BitmapFont();
        font.getData().scale(1.0f);
        font.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    }

    private void initInputListener(){
        setBounds(0, 0, Info.SCREEN_WIDTH, Info.SCREEN_HEIGHT);

        addListener(new InputListener(){

            @Override
            public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                targetActive = true;
                position.set(x, y).add(0, yOffset);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void touchDragged(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer) {
                position.set(x, y).add(0, yOffset);
            }

            @Override
            public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                targetActive = false;
            }

            @Override
            public void exit(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, Actor toActor) {
                targetActive = false;
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void act(float delta) {
        super.act(delta);
        if(targetActive && hasLink){
            updateUnprojectedPosition();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
        if(targetActive){
            batch.end();

            Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_BLEND);
            Gdx.gl.glBlendFunc(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

            shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(getStage().getCamera().combined);
            shapeRenderer.begin();

            // Render target
            Gdx.gl20.glLineWidth(3);
            shapeRenderer.set(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Line);
            shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.RED);
            shapeRenderer.circle(position.x, position.y, 32);
            shapeRenderer.circle(position.x, position.y, 1);


            // Render position text background
            Vector2 fontPosition = position.cpy().add(64, 64);
            shapeRenderer.set(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
            shapeRenderer.setColor(0, 0, 0, 0.5f);
            shapeRenderer.rect(fontPosition.x - 8, fontPosition.y - 32, 172, 40);

            shapeRenderer.end();

            Gdx.gl.glDisable(GL20.GL_BLEND);
            Gdx.gl20.glLineWidth(1);
            batch.setProjectionMatrix(getStage().getCamera().combined);
            batch.begin();

            // Render position text
            String text;
            if(hasLink)
                text = "(" + (int) unprojectedPosition.x + " , " + (int) unprojectedPosition.y + ")";
            else
                text = "No Link";

            font.draw(batch, text, fontPosition.x, fontPosition.y, 100, 10, false);
        }
        super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);
    }

    public void updateUnprojectedPosition(){
        Vector2 screenPosV2 = localToScreenCoordinates(position.cpy());
        Vector3 posV3 = new Vector3(screenPosV2.x, screenPosV2.y, 0);
        linkedCamera.unproject(posV3);
        unprojectedPosition.set(MathUtils.round(posV3.x), MathUtils.round(posV3.y));
    }

    public void linkToCamera(OrthographicCamera camera){
        if(camera != null){
            linkedCamera = camera;
            hasLink = true;
        }
    }

}
```

The `linkedCamera` is assigned in a manager class that handles the relationship between all HUD actions and the build area grid.

- This is my first time ever asking a question here, I'm sorry if I'm being too verbose but the issue is complicated to explain, at least it was for me.

Comment: LibGDX project() and unproject() are not inverses of each other. One of them flips Y and the other doesn't. Check the Javadocs carefully.

Comment: According to the Javadocs they are inverses of each other:                                 
                                                                        project() - Projects the Vector3 given in world space to screen coordinates.

unproject() - Function to translate a point given in screen coordinates to world space.

https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Camera.html

Comment: You need to read the expanded descriptions further down on that page. They describe which way Y is assumed to be pointing.

Comment: Ah I see what you are saying. While that is good to know since I would have assumed project() wouldn't flip the Y, it doesn't speak to my issue. My android build offsets the Y based on camera zoom, while my desktop build does not(desirable). In both builds the Y is pointing where it is supposed to. Good news is that I just figured out the problem and will post my answer. Thank you for that information.